# Erase the [notes]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[notes](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/notes) is an undefined tag with multiple uses:

- The "Notes" feature of various software
- The Notes page in PowerPoint
- Small text files
- Endnote
- Lotus Notes
- Notes 9 Webmail
- Evernote
- MS Onenote
- Request for software recommendation (off-topic)
- Questions about note mechanics (how are they stored/transmitted)
- How to open specific filetypes
- Diagnosing errors
- Comments
- Convert notes to different formats
- Permission issues
- Capturing script as a note
- etc...

Many of these uses already have a dedicated tag.  Notes are a specialized function, so note-specific tags are useful.  Recommend deleting the [notes] tag and creating more specific tags for those questions that are not already covered by an existing tag.

Comment: [Much Ado About **Noting**](http://www.shmoop.com/much-ado-about-nothing/noting-symbol.html)?    :-)    ⁠

Comment: @Scott that site is like straight out of geocities circa 1996.. geez!